# igraph: fast way to get edge attributes

Tags: r, igraph

I found it slow to get edge weight (or other edge attributes), using igraph 0.7.1. Surprisingly, the computing time for getting attribute for one edge is not too much different from getting the attribute for the whole edges:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g = erdos.renyi.game(10000,0.1)
E(g)$weight  = runif( ecount(g) )

system.time( E(g)[1]$weight )
system.time( E(g)[1:1E2]$weight )
system.time( E(g)[1:1E4]$weight )
system.time( E(g)[1:1E6]$weight )
system.time( E(g)[1:ecount(g)]$weight )
```

Or even, the time to retrieve one edge is not that much different from the time to retrieve the whole edges:

```
system.time( E(g)[1] )
system.time( E(g)[1:1E2] )
system.time( E(g)[1:1E4] )
system.time( E(g)[1:1E6] )
system.time( E(g)[1:ecount(g)] )
```

Or even, the time to compute the strength of one vertex is not that much different from the time to compute the strength of the whole vertices:

```
system.time( strength(g, 1) )
system.time( strength(g, 1:1E2) )
system.time( strength(g, 1:1E4) )
system.time( strength(g) )
```

To go back to my objective, how can I efficiently retrieve the weight of the edges between a node, e.g., 1, and other nodes, e.g., 2:10. One possible way is using the following code, which however is inefficient:

```
g[1, 2：10]
```

Comment: `system.time(edge_attr(g, "weight", 1))` is instant for me. I guess that's the correct way. Not sure about strength, though it already seems tolerable/fast to me.

Comment: The reason one edge takes just as long as all edges is because you are creating the object E(g) and then subsetting it.